# How can I divide and multiply each row/column (cell) value in R?

Tags: r

I have this dataframe called `mydf`.

```
mydf<- structure(list(length = 18:21, A = c(40889L, 42585L, 60586L, 
73374L), C = c(24283L, 66371L, 30027L, 40899L), G = c(38245L, 
29170L, 37877L, 49023L), T = c(92544L, 159373L, 326940L, 654364L
)), .Names = c("length", "A", "C", "G", "T"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to perform mathematical function like below in `mydf` dataframe. In other words, I want to divide each value by a number (say x) and multiply by 100.

```
 length     A            C            G             T
     18 (40889/x)*100 (24283/x)*100 (38245/x)*100   (92544/x)*100
     19 (42585/x)*100 (66371/x)*100 (29170/x)*100 (159373/x)*100
     20 (60586/x)*100 (30027/)*100 (37877/x)*100 (326940/x)*100
     21 (73374/x)*100 (40899/x)*100 (49023/x) (654364/x)*100
```

Comment: What's `x` though?

Comment: @useR x is any integer.

Comment: @caseWestern That didn't work. I already tried it.

Comment: Apply the transformation and update just the desired columns `mydf[-1] = (mydf[-1] / 5) * 100`

Comment: Yo have to exclude the first column by specifying mydf[,-1]. I posted the answer down.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the job:

```
x = 5
cbind(length = mydf[,1], (mydf[,-1]/x)*100)
```

With `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-1), funs(./x*100))
```

**Result:**

```
  length       A       C      G        T
1     18  817780  485660 764900  1850880
2     19  851700 1327420 583400  3187460
3     20 1211720  600540 757540  6538800
4     21 1467480  817980 980460 13087280
```

Answer (score 0):

for column A:

```
mydf$A <- ((mydf$A / x)*100)
```

You should be able to google this as it is basic.

Comment: Yes it is basic. I just failed to conver character values to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- 4 
mydf <- cbind(mydf[1], ( mydf[2:ncol(mydf)] / x) * 100)
```

Result:

```
  length       A       C       G        T
1     18 1022225  607075  956125  2313600
2     19 1064625 1659275  729250  3984325
3     20 1514650  750675  946925  8173500
4     21 1834350 1022475 1225575 16359100
```

To apply to specific columns:

```
specific_cols <- which(names(mydf) %in% c('A', 'G', 'T'))

specific_result <- cbind(mydf[-specific_cols], ( mydf[specific_cols] / x) * 100)
```

Result:

```
  length     C       A       G        T
1     18 24283 1022225  956125  2313600
2     19 66371 1064625  729250  3984325
3     20 30027 1514650  946925  8173500
4     21 40899 1834350 1225575 16359100
```

Comment: @userR I fixed the answer

Comment: @caseWestern Thanks. This is what I have done, but I think my dataframe values are not numeric. Worked when I converted to matrix.

Comment: @MAPK the dataframe you provided in your question actually has numeric columns. If this doesn't reflect the "real" dataframe you have, please update the sample dataframe so people won't be confused.

Comment: @MAPK, if any of your columns are non-numeric, you can specify those to leave out of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

dplyr solution

```
mydf %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c("A","C","G","T")),funs(.*x/100))
```

data.table solution

```
DT <- setDT(mydf)
DT[,.SD*x/100,.SDcols = c("A","C","G","T")]
```

and base

```
mydf[c("A","C","G","T")] <- mydf[c("A","C","G","T")]*x/100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydf
length     A     C     G      T
1     18 40889 24283 38245  92544
2     19 42585 66371 29170 159373
3     20 60586 30027 37877 326940
4     21 73374 40899 49023 654364
x<-2
mydf[,-1]<-(mydf[-1]/x)*100
mydf
length       A       C       G        T
1     18 2044450 1214150 1912250  4627200
2     19 2129250 3318550 1458500  7968650
3     20 3029300 1501350 1893850 16347000
4     21 3668700 2044950 2451150 32718200
```